# How to fix flex box with justify-content space between

Tags: html, css

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class=item>Box 1</div>
  <div class=item>Box 2</div>
  <div class=item>Box 3</div>
  <div class=item>Box 4</div>
  <div class=item>Box 5</div>
</div>
```

My question is, how can I move the `Box 5` next to `Box 4` without the space between them?  At the moment, the `Box 5` is move to right end, and `Box 4` is stay on the left.

Comment: I would not use this principle of constructing squares on the page, use the table.

Comment: You just need to remove `justify-content:space-between;` Your problem will get solve. :)

Comment: No, I need the justify-content, so I can use the full space of the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific layout the problem arises for the `3n + 2` child `.item` if it is also the `last-child` child: for that element adjust the right margin

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 70px;
}

.container :last-child:nth-child(3n + 2) {
   margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class=item>Box 1</div>
  <div class=item>Box 2</div>
  <div class=item>Box 3</div>
  <div class=item>Box 4</div>
  <div class=item>Box 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: add explanation and how it works, thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of way you can achieve this. Just remove `justify-content` property from your style. It will be fine.

And you can also wrap `box 4` and `box 5`, and give the root container(in this case: item-special-container) `display: flex`.

```css
.container {
width:400px;
border:2px solid red;
display:flex;
flex-flow:row wrap;
justify-content:space-between;
}

.item {
padding:20px;
border:1px solid blue;
margin:10px;
width:70px;
}
.item-special-container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class=item>Box 1</div>
  <div class=item>Box 2</div>
  <div class=item>Box 3</div>
  <div class="item-special-container">
    <div class=item>Box 4</div>
    <div class=item>Box 5</div>
  <div>
</div>
```

Comment: add explanation and how it works, thanks